# Is this a clipless pedal?

Tags: pedals, pedals-clipless

I have bough a 2nd handed road bike recently. The seller said that the pedal could work as both platform pedal and clipless pedal.

Is it true? If yes, which system of clipless shoes can it work with?

[image: The pedal]

Comment: No, it's not a clipless pedal. If you buya cage and straps it can probably work as a clip-in pedal though.

Comment: Does it have a brand name on it?

Comment: It's a plain old "platform" pedal.  The screw holes would allow one to add a toe clip.

Comment: @andy256 Nope, just plain black

Comment: Those are VP pedals, you can still [buy that exact model online](http://www.mrcyclingworld.com.au/road-pedals-straps-clips).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either the seller meant *clipped* pedal-as in you could bolt toe clips to it-or he didn't know what he was talking about. Those are **not** clipless pedals. They are VP road pedals that have an integrated toeclip:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

As the comments said, adding a toe clip would make it a clipless pedal.

It may be too narrow for a platform pedal (depends on the width of your foot). The foot could slip sideways off the pedal.

Comment: Adding a toe clip would make it a clipp**ed** pedal.

Comment: I'd say it's pretty normal size for a platform pedal.